# Win32 C++ Console application not installing in windows server 8 beta 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

We had few Visual C++ Applications which was running fine in windows server 2003.Now we are migrating to Windows 8 server. We copied all the Supporting DLL's and trying to install the EXE in Windows 8 server.

Getting the Below Error **"Application as requested the Runtime to terminate in a unusual way"**

When i saw in the Eventviewer

```
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x00009754
Faulting process id: 0xf30
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd5ff1604c6270
```

and

> Fault bucket -1232291099, type 1 Event Name: APPCRASH Response: Not
>   available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: AutoClose.exe P2: 0.0.0.0 P3: 4a367b0e P4:
>   AutoClose.exe P5: 0.0.0.0 P6: 4a367b0e P7: 40000015 P8: 00009754 P9: 
>   P10:
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   9e00789a-cbe4-11e1-ba02-00155d50a602 Report Status: 0 Hashed bucket:
>   e2a5b7c6aeac3248eac86ce4c4691b6e

Any Suggestions

Comment: Do you have the source code for these applications? Can you attach a debugger to them?

Comment: Am not abl to attach  a debugger in 2012 server. See if you can help [iis-debugging-in-windows-2012-server-iis-8-0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534657/iis-debugging-in-windows-2012-server-iis-8-0)