# IIS debugging in windows 2012 server IIS 8.0

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, iis

Am trying to debug the web application hosted in windows  server 2012 with IIS 8.0. I opened VS2008 with the code and i Attach process but no W3Wp.exe process is listed there.

In task manager i can see the w3wp.exe under **details** tab not in **Procees** tab. In process tab IIS worker Process is listed.

Checked all users and all sessions as well

Please let me know how i can debug.

Thanks

Comment: 'Show processes from all users' checked?

Comment: Ya i checked.But not listed there too

Comment: This works for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462016/w3wp-process-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Ticking 'Show processes in all sessions' showed it for me

Comment: Where is this checkbox you speak of?